# Submitting form to mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, forms

I think i have everything right, but I don't see the values in my database. I linked my form correctly to the javascript and i seem to have put the right queries in my code, but it still doesn't work.

My html markup with the form in it, I linked all js in head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript sample: Form Validation & Sql insertion</title>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="databaseManager.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_always_insert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="verstuurData.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td>Voornaam</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="voor"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Achternaam</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="achter"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="email"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Wachtwoord</td>
    <td><input type="password" id="wachtwoord" onkeyup="verstuurData();"/> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="create" value="Create" 
onclick="validate();finalValidate();"/></td>
    <td><div id="errFinal"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript/ link to send form data to mysql database:

```
var dbHost = "-";
    var myToken = "-";
    mDatabaseManager.connect(dbHost);
    mDatabaseManager.authenticate(myToken);

    var tableNaam = "persoon";

    function verstuurData() {
        var persoonGegevens = new Array();
        persoonGegevens[0] = document.getElementById('voor').value;
        persoonGegevens[1] = document.getElementById('achter').value;
        persoonGegevens[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
        persoonGegevens[3] = document.getElementById('wachtwoord').value;

        var maakTabel = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableNaam + "(" + 
            " 'voornaam' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " +
            " 'achternaam' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " + 
            " 'email' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, " +
            " 'wachtwoord' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, ";

        mDatabasemanager
            .query(maakTabel)
            .done(function(verzenden) { 

                var dataZettenPersoon = "INSERT INTO" + tableNaam + "(" + 
                    "'voornaam' , 'achternaam' , 'email' , 'wachtwoord') " +
                    " VALUES ('" 
                    + persoonGegevens[0]
                    + "','"
                    + persoonGegevens[1]
                    + "','" 
                    + persoonGegevens[2]
                    + "','"
                    + persoonGegevens[3]
                    + "')";

        mDatabaseManager
            .query(dataZettenPersoon)
            .done(function(data) {
                        })
                        .fail(function(reason) {
                            console.log(reason);
                    });

                })
                .fail(function(reason) {
                    console.log(reason);
                });
    }
```

Comment: What is `mDatabaseManager`?

Comment: to be honest , i dont know, i wrote this javascript looking at another js that also uses mDatabaseManager, but in that js, i couldnt also really see what it is, i dont see it being defined.

Comment: @Pakjethee How much JavaScript do you know? I think you may need to go back and learn some of the basis.

Comment: thanks to all of your help, expected more help from you, instead of criticism. Thanks

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? We're trying to help, but we need information in order to do so. See [ask] for some tips on what is expected in a question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot query a database directly from Javascript (at least not using plain javascript with no libraries).

Your Javascript code should call a server-side function (that you can write in PHP, C#, etc.), which queries the database and returns the results to your Javascript code.

This example may be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp

Comment: OP, PHP has a nice way to interaction with MySQL. It's called mysqli, you just call it with a few parameters (username/password, database, etc) and you're on your way. Good documentation out there and not too hard to work through it

Comment: using PHP's PDO object is also a good option + it's more general (database does not need to be MySql)

Comment: the bad thing about this school project is that we're not allowed to use php :/